# 'bad input shape' when using scikit-learn SVM and optunity

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation

I'm trying to use [optunity package](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/python/sklearn/svc.html) to tuning my SVM model, I'm directly copy and past it's up-to-date example code , just import the feature array and data array

```
import optunity
import optunity.metrics
import sklearn.svm
import numpy as np

data_path = '/python/Feature'
files = ['A.npy', 'B.npy', 'C.npy']

array = []
labels = []

for i,name in enumerate(files):
    data = np.load('{}/{}'.format(data_path, name))
    for j in range(0,len(data)):
        labels.append(data[j])
        array.append(data)

print len(array)   #=> 1247
print len(labels)  #=> 1247

# score function: twice iterated 10-fold cross-validated accuracy
@optunity.cross_validated(x=data, y=labels, num_folds=10, num_iter=2)
def svm_auc(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, C, gamma):
    model = sklearn.svm.SVC(C=C, gamma=gamma).fit(x_train, y_train)
    decision_values = model.decision_function(x_test)
    return optunity.metrics.roc_auc(y_test, decision_values)

# perform tuning
optimal_pars, _, _ = optunity.maximize(svm_auc, num_evals=200, C=[0, 10], gamma=[0, 1])

# train model on the full training set with tuned hyperparameters
optimal_model = sklearn.svm.SVC(**optimal_pars).fit(data, labels)
```

However ,compiler looks very unhappy , I have looked at [SVM class document](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC) to double check the input format ,however I don't understand optunity's coding syntax .. can anyone help me find out what's going wrong there? Really appreciated .. (I'm using 'rbf' kernel , I tried to add in but syntax goes wrong , it's strange in optunity's example there is no kernel selection.. )

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/SVM_turning.py", line 26, in <module>
    optimal_pars, _, _ = optunity.maximize(svm_auc, num_evals=200, C=[0, 10], gamma=[0, 1])
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/optunity/api.py", line 181, in maximize
    pmap=pmap)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/optunity/api.py", line 245, in optimize
    solution, report = solver.optimize(f, maximize, pmap=pmap)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/optunity/solvers/ParticleSwarm.py", line 257, in optimize
    fitnesses = pmap(evaluate, list(map(self.particle2dict, pop)))
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/optunity/solvers/ParticleSwarm.py", line 246, in evaluate
    return f(**d)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/optunity/functions.py", line 286, in wrapped_f
    value = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/optunity/functions.py", line 341, in wrapped_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/optunity/constraints.py", line 150, in wrapped_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/optunity/constraints.py", line 128, in wrapped_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/optunity/constraints.py", line 265, in func
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/optunity/cross_validation.py", line 386, in __call__
    scores.append(self.f(**kwargs))
  File "/python/SVM_turning.py", line 21, in svm_auc
    model = sklearn.svm.SVC(C=C, gamma=gamma).fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 138, in fit
    y = self._validate_targets(y)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 441, in _validate_targets
    y_ = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 319, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (428, 600)
```

Comment: The code seems fine, we are currently unable to reproduce this issue (unfortunately). I will get back to this shortly. I've also made a GitHub issue about this: https://github.com/claesenm/optunity/issues/43.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem. You are preparing the lists `array` and `labels` while reading files. `array` gets filled with `data` sequentially. However, later, you do this:

```
@optunity.cross_validated(x=data, y=labels, num_folds=10, num_iter=2)
```

and

```
optimal_model = sklearn.svm.SVC(**optimal_pars).fit(data, labels)
```

and hence use `data` as your data set, rather than `array` which you prepared. I don't know the format of what you're reading from files, so I can't say for sure what's going on. However, the dimensions of `data` and `labels` almost surely won't match.

Here's a toy example with `array` and `labels` that does work properly:

```
import optunity
import optunity.metrics
import sklearn.svm
import numpy as np

#print len(array)   #=> 1247
#print len(labels)  #=> 1247

# make dummy data
array = np.array([[i] for i in range(1247)])
labels = [True] * 100 + [False] * 1147

# score function: twice iterated 10-fold cross-validated accuracy
@optunity.cross_validated(x=array, y=labels, num_folds=10, num_iter=2)
def svm_auc(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, C, gamma):
    model = sklearn.svm.SVC(C=C, gamma=gamma).fit(x_train, y_train)
    decision_values = model.decision_function(x_test)
    return optunity.metrics.roc_auc(y_test, decision_values)

# perform tuning
optimal_pars, _, _ = optunity.maximize(svm_auc, num_evals=200, C=[0, 10], gamma=[0, 1])

# train model on the full training set with tuned hyperparameters
optimal_model = sklearn.svm.SVC(**optimal_pars).fit(array, labels)
print(optimal_pars)
```

Which outputs (example):

> {'C': 8.0126953125, 'gamma': 0.35791015625}

Sorry for taking so long to reply.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see what the default optimizer in optunity is, but if you just use grid search, you can use GridSearchCV in scikit-learn.

Your example looks pretty much like the documentation in optunity. Have you tried running the exact example that is on there?

Comment: Optunity's default optimizer is particle swarm optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your error at all but I got this when I was using regular arrays when I should have been using Numpy.